# NRC Latex Template

Tags: header-footer

[image]

Does anybody know how to edit the 'unknown' in the NRC journal? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .log file, you will probably find a warning, that no journal is specified - to rectify this:

```
\journal{text}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{nrc1}

\title{Title}
\author{Author One}
\address{Address One}
\correspond{author@email.address}
\shortauthor{One et al.}
\journal{Biochem. Cell Biol.}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

See the "NRC: LATEX User Guide for Journals", Appendix A for a full list of journals.

Comment: The problem is solved as you said. Thanks a lot.